# Android claiming Unity Engine apk is unsafe even with signing key?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, code-signing, android-install-apk

It's possible that I'm not understanding something but here's how I though this works:

Without a signing key (Or when using Unity's debug signing key) Android would claim an app to be unsafe but would let you install the app. However once you got a signing key android would still tell you to me careful, but wouldn't give you several warning messages about installing the apk file.

But this doesn't appear to be the case, I just created a signing key through Unity and I can even verify the key is active when looking at the apk on Virustotal.

For example, when I install an application called [NewPipe](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe) this is the only message I get before install or updating the app. (I just noticed it's mentioning updating the application. That's because I already have the app installed, but even when that app wasn't installed the message looks very similar to this and there is still only 1 warning)

[image]

But when I try to install my own application, with or without a signing key, I get the message I got above with Newpipe, then I get this message:

[image]

If both apps have their own signing key, why does Newpipe only show one warning, while my app shows several?

Answer (score 0):

When you signed the app it is ready for uploading the app to stores. And when you are signing the app you are setting the developer name. And when you uploading the apk to play store signes it again with another signature. And I think android searches for that signature and when it can't find it, it gives you warning message.

Comment: Interesting, so you think if I were to upload this app to Google Play and then make another app with the same signing key I would no longer get the second warning?

Comment: No. Play store signes the app in store. But when directly downloading there is no second signature.

Comment: But Newpipe isn't nor has it ever been in the Play Store, so why doesn't Newpipe get the second warning?

Comment: Did you signed the app when isn't second warning?

Comment: I can't get the second warning to disappear whether I sign the app or not. My point is that another app that doesn't exist on the Play Store doesn't throw out that second warning, why is that?

Comment: I think if you don't sign the app unity's default signe doesn't give you a error.

Comment: I've already created my own signing key that isn't the default debug key and it's giving me that error.

Comment: But you didn't put it to play store. Play store signes the app too.

Comment: But Newpipe isn't on the Play Store ether, so that isn't the issue. Your going in circles.